# When was a VBA Macro last modified

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I want to tell when was my macro was was last used.

I have a macro that updates all the time and it's on different computers, so from time to time it's harder to track whichever of the macros is the latest.

I would like to know:

1. Can I tell when was a VBA Macro last modified?
2. Can I see log of use in the macro?
3. Can I add a comment with date of use in the VBA itself

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Can I tell when was a VBA Macro last modified?

No, there is no such level of logging in Excel (neither any other MS Office applications)

> 2. Can I see log of use in the macro?

No, there is no such level of logging in Excel (neither any other MS Office applications)

> 3. Can I add a comment with date of use in the VBA itself

Yes, you can modify your code using macro, however modifying the running code might be risky.
You can find example code e.g. in this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961711/excel-vba-programmatically-insertline-of-code-to-a-specific-sub-macro-in-a-wor

Comment: Thank you I will definitely test the third  one

Answer (score 0):

VBA does not provide these facilities out of the box.  However it is perfectly feasible to define a class which provides your macro and which manages a 'LastUsed' function and a log of each time the function was called.

Edited 2019-Oct-15  to add code to find a method in VBA projects

The following code extracts the text of a method so you now have a facility to compare the method at different time intervals.

```
Public Sub TestGetMethodText()

    Debug.Print GetMethodText("GetMethodText")

End Sub


Public Function GetMethodText(ByVal MethodName As String) As String
' Requires a reference to 'Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility'
' Assumes the Method name is unique in any of the modules/classes in any open projects.

Dim myProject                               As VBIDE.VBProject
Dim myComponent                             As VBIDE.VBComponent
Dim myProcKind                              As VBIDE.vbext_ProcKind

    GetMethodText = "Not Found"

    For Each myProject In VBE.VBProjects

        For Each myComponent In myProject.VBComponents

            With myComponent.CodeModule

                myFirstLine = 1
                myProcKind = 0

                If .Find("Function " & MethodName, 1, 1, -1, -1) Then

                    GetMethodText = _
                        .Lines _
                        ( _
                            .ProcBodyLine(MethodName, myProcKind), _
                            .ProcCountLines(MethodName, myProcKind) _
                        )
                     Exit Function

                End If

            End With

        Next

    Next

End Function
```

Comment: and where will this log be saved to?

Comment: The location and style of any log would be entirely your decision.